# .NET - ExecuteNonQuery returning 0 after deleting two Rows

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm having the following problem: I have a SQL Server stored procedure that receives two parameters and makes a delete statement for all the records matching the criteria.

Something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TableDelete]   
   @IdOne bigint,  
   @IdTwo varchar(30)  
AS  
BEGIN  
   DELETE dbo.GdcBridgeQualidadeOrgao  
   WHERE IdOne = @IdOne 
     AND IdTwo = @IdTwo 
END
```

Next, I have a method in .NET that uses the `ExecuteNonQuery` method to call that stored procedure with the parameters filled up.

What's making me insane is:

1. If I call the `ExecuteNonQuery` to delete 1 row that meets the criteria on the table, the `ExecuteNonQuery` returns 1. This is correct, 1 row was affected.
2. However, if I try to call the `ExecuteNonQuery` to delete 2 rows, the `ExecuteNonQuery` returns 0, instead of 2!

Any idea?

Comment: are you sure you mean AND - and not OR ?

Comment: share your .net code from where you are calling stored procedure

Comment: clearly means that you are passing wrong arguments or condition is not correct and hence nothing is deleted and so you get 0 in return

Comment: Have you `SET NOCOUNT ON `?

Comment: You seem to assume that ExecuteNonQuery has a bug and returns the wrong number. This is a very questionable assumption. Rather, your query is probably wrong or your data is.

Comment: Can you post an actual repro that demonstrates this behavior?  The ExecuteNonQuery method should simply sum the returned row counts (DONE_IN_PROC TDS protocol messages) and return that result as the number of rows affected.  Are there any triggers on the table?